# How to set a default selected value using selectize.js?

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

i want set a default select  value in two and three, any one please help,
i have used below code.

```
<select id="select-state"  multiple class="demo-default" name="material[]" >  <option seleted="true" value="1">one</option>   <option seleted="true" value="2">two</option>   <option seleted="true" value="3">Three</option>   <option seleted="true" value="4">Four</option>
```

script code

```
<script>   $('#select-state').selectize({    maxItems: 500    });  </script>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your problem but you have misspelt "selected" as "seleted" on all your options.

Comment: just i have tried selected but not work

Comment: Yes, i have corrected spelling, now its working fine Thanks @Dr